# MySQL Error 1054: Setting column name and use to where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, select

how i use where clause with a new columns names?

```
SELECT 
    IF(cond, 'yes', 'no') AS 'NEW_COLUMN'
FROM
    table
WHERE
    NEW_COLUMN = 'yes'
```

MySQL Error 1054: Unknown Column 'NEW_COLUMN' in 'where clause'

Comment: Your example SQL can be refactored to `SELECT 'yes' FROM table WHERE cond`

Comment: @paul: write it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most versions of SQL you need to use a subquery, common table expression, or repeat the logic.  MySQL extends the use of the `having` clause to handle this.

So, the following non-standard SQL works in MySQL:

```
SELECT IF(cond, 'yes', 'no') AS 'NEW_COLUMN'
FROM table
HAVING NEW_COLUMN = 'yes';
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about your 'actual' use case, but you can easily achieve your exmaple by refactoring the SQL thus:

`SELECT 'yes' FROM table WHERE cond`